# Copy worksheet into new workbook and save

Tags: excel, vba, copy

1. Copy Worksheet 1 in Workbook A
2. Create new Workbook (named as below)
3. Copy worksheet 1 into new workbook
4. Save new workbook as 'abc (daily) & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyy") & ".xlsm" - i.e. code will save in a way that depends on today's date

I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake

```
'Save Worksheet1 as Workbook
Worksheets("Worksheet 1").Activate
With Worksheets("Worksheet 1")
    .copy
End With
saveLocation = "X:\abc\abc\abc (daily)" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyy") & ".xlsm"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypexlsm, _
    Filename:=saveLocation
```

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` can't be used to save as an xlsm, but is for `PDF` and `XPS` formats. Use `SaveAs` on the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopySheetAsNewWorkbook()

Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook

'currentWorkbook is the source workbook, create a new workbook referencing to it with theNewWorkbook
Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set theNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

'do the copy (it's better to check if there is already a 'Worksheet 1' in the new workbook. It it exists delete it or rename it
currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet 1").Copy before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Remove default sheets in order to have only the copied sheet inside the new workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = theNewWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    theNewWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Save File as XLSM
saveLocation = "X:\abc\abc\abc (daily)" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyy") & ".xlsm"
theNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=saveLocation, FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
theNewWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
Sub test()
Path = "D:\"
Filename = "test "
Sheets("Worksheet 1").Copy
' for multiple sheets : Sheets(Array("TABEL", "DATA", "BACKUP")).Copy
' to save with time : ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & Format(Now(), "yymmdd hh mm ss") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & Format(Date, "ddmmyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Export

- **Before running the code**, adjust the values of variables `NewFilePath`
  and `SourceSheet` in `Sub exportFirst`. `NewFilePath` must **not** end with a backslash `\`.
- The code is written to refer to a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` i.e. the workbook
  containing this code.
- `Sub exportFirst` is calling `Sub exportWorksheet`.
- You can write several subs like `Sub exportFirst` for other
  worksheets in the workbook.
- I would prefer using e.g. `Worksheets("Sheets1")` over
  `Worksheets(1)`.
- After you are done testing the code, you should probably un-comment the
  line `.Close`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportFirst()

    Const NewFilePath As String _
      = "C:\Test"

    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    exportWorksheet SourceSheet, NewFilePath

End Sub

Sub exportWorksheet(SourceSheet As Worksheet, NewFilePath As String)

    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim SaveLocation As String

    ' Either:
'    ' If you want to name the new workbook using 'SourceSheet.Name':
    NewFileName = SourceSheet.Name
'    ' Or:
'    ' If you want to name the new workbook using 'ThisWorkbook.Name':
'    NewFileName _
'      = Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)

    ' I would prefer "yyyymmdd" or at least "ddmmmyyyy"
    SaveLocation = NewFilePath & "\" & NewFileName & " (daily)" _
      & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyy")

    SourceSheet.Copy

    With ActiveWorkbook

        ' Either:
        ' .xlsm
        SaveLocation = SaveLocation & ".xlsm"
        .SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
          Filename:=SaveLocation

        ' or:
        ' .xlsx
'        SaveLocation = SaveLocation & ".xlsx"
'        .SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
'          Filename:=SaveLocation

        ' or:
        ' .csv
'        SaveLocation = SaveLocation & ".csv"
'        .SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Filename:=SaveLocation

        ' or:
        ' .pdf
'        SaveLocation = SaveLocation & ".pdf"
'        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SaveLocation
'        .Saved = True

        '.Close ' You should use '.Close' always with '.pdf'.

    End With

End Sub
```