# Copy worksheet into new workbook without macros or formulas and save

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I followed @VBasic2008 guidance from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493924/copy-worksheet-into-new-workbook-and-save) and was able to copy one worksheet and save it in a specified folder with the naming convention I want. In addition the formatting of the sheet remains the same.

The issue I am running into is that the new workbook still has formulas which change based on the original workbook. How would I modify the below code so that the original workbook is unchanged but the new workbook contains the same formatting but has values instead of formulas? I am able to save the file as an .xlsx so I assume that the macros are not carried over though I am unsure if this is the case.

```vb
Sub exportFirst()

    Const NewFilePath As String _
      = "C:\Users\Feketenyek\Test Folder"

    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    exportWorksheet SourceSheet, NewFilePath

End Sub

Sub exportWorksheet(SourceSheet As Worksheet, NewFilePath As String)

    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim SaveLocation As String

 
    NewFileName = "File Prefix " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Auto_Pop").Range("A2") & " File Suffix"

    SaveLocation = NewFilePath & "\" & NewFileName

    SourceSheet.Copy
    
    With ActiveWorkbook

        SaveLocation = SaveLocation & ".xlsx"
        .SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
          FileName:=SaveLocation
        .Close 

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: After `With ActiveWorkbook` add new line `.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value`

Comment: @CDP1802 that seems to have worked; thank you very much!

Comment: Also, instead of the first `ActiveWorkbook`, you should use `SourceSheet.Parent` and instead of the second one, you should use `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`.

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, I am unsure where to make these changes. What effect will they have on the original worksheet?

Comment: 1.) `... & SourceSheet.Parent.Sheets(...` i.e. `SourceSheet.Parent` is the workbook of the passed worksheet (`SourceSheet`) which may or may not be the active workbook. 2.) `With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`: I forgot the reason when `ActiveWorkbook` wouldn't work.